# Параметры GET request в Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get

Как написать запрос таким образом чтоб я мог например авторизоваться в приложение по ссылке вида *example.com?Authorization=sometoken* , мой payload

```
  def payload
    auth_header = request.headers['Authorization']
    token = auth_header.split(' ').last
    JsonWebToken.decode(token)
  rescue
    nil
  end
```

Может есть какой-нибудь параметр request по типу request.query? Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решается очень просто с изменением `request.headers` на `request.query_parameters`